# Exception when downloading file from box.com - Android

Tags: android, box

I am trying to download a file using the Box android SDK. The problem seems to be with the destinationFile parameter. The box.com call is checking whether the destinationFile exists - but why? I get java.io.FileNotFoundException.

```
destinationFile = new File(getFilesDir(), "myfile.crs");
        // destinationFile = new File(getFilesDir(),"/");
        try {
            BoxDownload fileDownload = mFileApi.getDownloadRequest(destinationFile, fileID)
                    // Optional: Set a listener to track download progress.
                    .setProgressListener(new ProgressListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onProgressChanged(long numBytes, long totalBytes) {
                            // Update a progress bar, etc.
                        }
                    })
                    .send();
        } catch (BoxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: The exception is telling you.... The file is not found. That file, is more than likely not in the location you expect it to be, so step through your code and check please.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't make sense to me. I'm trying to download the file from box.com so why would the first line be to check and throw an exception? Of course it doesn't exist, it needs to be downloaded.             public BoxRequestsFile.DownloadFile getDownloadRequest(File target, String fileId) throws IOException{
            if (!target.exists()){
                throw new FileNotFoundException();
            }
            BoxRequestsFile.DownloadFile request = new BoxRequestsFile.DownloadFile(target, getFileDownloadUrl(fileId),mSession);
            return request;
    }

Comment: Has anyone gotten Box to work with Android for downloading files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to create a new File. Then call .createNewFile() on the File instance. Then call all of the code I posted except to put run it in the background. That's why I was asking here - I was wondering if I was doing something incorrect for Android and I was. Box networking operations need to be done on a thread.
Too bad they never show this for downloading a file. Too bad there's not one example of downloading a file with the Android DSK on the web.

Answer (score 0):

To do All the checks

```
Log.i(getClass().getName(),"Does File exists:"+(destinationFile.exists()?"Yes":"No"));
        Log.i(getClass().getName(),"Is it A file:"+(destinationFile.isFile()?"Yes":"No"));
        Log.i(getClass().getName(),"Is it Writable:"+(destinationFile.canWrite()?"Yes":"No"));
        Log.i(getClass().getName(),"Is it A Readable:"+(destinationFile.canRead()?"Yes":"No"));
        Log.i(getClass().getName(),"Path:"+destinationFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

you are most likely to found file does not exists then do this before using it.

```
if(!destinationFile.exists()){
            try {
                destinationFile.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: I have to be missing something obvious. If I call createNewFile(), then I get an "unexpected box exception".